# Background video loop not working in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avfoundation, avplayer

I have been created page control, and in that the background videos will be get loaded, the videos is getting played but the loop is not working, **i had refered in stackoverflow**  but i couldn't get the right answer

here is mine code:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.pageController.currentPage = 0
    loadVideo(currentPage: 0)
 }

func loadVideo(currentPage: Int) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

    self.videoPath =  Bundle.main.url(forResource: "BoardVideoArray[currentPage]", withExtension: "mp4")

    self.player = AVPlayer(url: self.videoPath!)
    self.player?.actionAtItemEnd = .none
    self.player?.isMuted = true

   self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
    self.playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    self.playerLayer.zPosition = -1
    }

    playerLayer.frame = videoVIew.frame

     videoVIew.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
     videoVIew.bringSubview(toFront: pageController)

    player?.play()

    //loop video
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player?.currentItem, queue: nil, using: { (_) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.player?.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
            self.player = AVPlayer(url: self.videoPath!)
            self.player.play()
        }
    })

}
```

I have declared the player and avplayerLayer out of scope

```
   var player: AVPlayer!
   var playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
```

I spend more than 4 hours, but i couldn't found the mistake which i have made.
**The issue is video is not geting looping**

Comment: Try removing `self.player = AVPlayer(url: self.videoPath!)` and `self.player.play()` from your code. `seek` is just enough to loop your video.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "video", ofType:"m4v") else {
        debugPrint("video.m4v not found")
        return
    }
    //VideoPlayer is a subClass of AVPlayer
    let player = VideoPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
    playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    playerViewController.player = player
    //self.videoPlayerView is a UIView in which i want to show video.
    playerViewController.view.frame = self.videoPlayerView.bounds
    self.videoPlayerView.addSubview(playerViewController.view)
    playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = false
    playerViewController.player?.play()
    player.shouldMute(mute: true)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(HomeViewController.videoDidStopPlaying(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)


func videoDidStopPlaying(notification:Notification) {
        self.playerViewController.player?.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
        self.playerViewController.player?.play()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a Swift `UIView` subclass called `SDLoopingVideoView` that plays and loops any compatible `AVPlayer` video file and automatically scales it to fill the view. It can be entirely setup in Interface Builder This work great as a video background and you won't have to worry about the video looping since it's managed automatically. You can find it on Github here: [SDLoopingVideoView](https://github.com/SolsmaHawk/SDLoopingVideoView)